# Duplicate BondCodegen items were included

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have updated some Nuget Packages (through nuget package manager) for some projects in my .sln file based on dotnet framework 4.7.2

But I am getting the following error:
***Duplicate BondCodegen items were included. The Bond package includes BondCodegen items for all .bond files from your project directory by default. You can either remove these items from your project file, or set the 'EnableDefaultCompileItems' property to 'false' if you want to explicitly include them in your project file. To set per-item metadata, use the item update syntax (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-element-msbuild#examples)***

I have checked .csproj files of all the projects in the solution and the bond file related versions are:

Bond.Core.CSharp.9.0.5

Bond.CSharp.9.0.5

Bond.Runtime.CSharp.9.0.5

I can see the updated package reference as well but still not able to figure out the exact problem from last 2 days. Need help to solve this error.